# Parametrization of $3x^2+y^2-4z^2=1$, if $y=z^2-1$, $z\geq 0$

Tags: parametrization

How to make a Trigonometric Parametrization of $3x^2+y^2-4z^2=1$, if $y=z^2-1$, $z\geq 0$.
To find $\theta$ such that $r(\theta)=(\sqrt{3},2,\sqrt{2})$

**Attempt** Replacing the second equation on the first we arrived to
$$3x^2+y^2-4y-4=1 $$
which is an ellipse but, we know that the parametrization in such case $r=h+a\cos(t)$, $y=k+b\sin(t)$ here $(h,k)=(0,2)$ how to find $a,b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

Add 8 on both sides of equation and simplify
$$\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt3)^2}  +  \frac{(y-2)^2}{3^2} =1 $$
$$ \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t =1 $$

You want to put it into the form:

$x=h+a\cos(t)$, $y=k+b\sin(t)$ here $(h,k)=(0,2)$

Can you take it from here?